# How to use joomla pagination of my custom foreach loop data

Tags: php, joomla, pagination, joomla3.0

How to use **joomla pagination** in my custom **foreach loop** data.

```
    //My code
    <?php foreach ($items as $item) : ?>
    <h2><?= $item->name ?></h2> // data
    <?php endforeach; ?>


     //This code show pagination but not working
     $total = count($items);
     jimport('joomla.html.pagination');
     $pagination = new JPagination($total, 0 , 1);
     echo $pagination->getPagesLinks();
     echo $pagination->getPagesCounter();
```

Can you give a best solution?

Comment: Please post your Joomla questions on Joomla Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any idea to use joomla pagination.
So I create custom pagination.

```
    <?php  //my code
    $nItemsPerPage = 1;
    $nOfPage=intval(count($items)/$nItemsPerPage)+1;
    $page = isset($_GET['page'])?intval($_GET['page']-1):0;
    foreach(array_slice($items, $nItemsPerPage*($page-1), $nItemsPerPage) as $item): 

    echo $item->title; //output

    endforeach;
    ?> 

    //pagination
    <ul>
    <?php
    for($i=1;$i<$nOfPage;$i++) { ?>
    <li><a href='?page=<?php echo $i; ?>'><?php echo $i ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~Thank You~~~~~~~~~~